# Visualization of force-driven large graph: python and graphviz

Tags: python, igraph, graphviz, graph-visualization

I am working on community detection algorithms, and I am currently trying to visualize the results of Louvain algorithm (https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0476) on a graph of 70K nodes and 8M edges.

I plotted a smaller graph before (20K nodes, 650K edges) with `igraph` by taking inspiration from [How to plot Community-based graph using igraph for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443030/how-to-plot-community-based-graph-using-igraph-for-python), and it took almost 30 minutes. Plotting 70K nodes and 8M edges takes 8 hours.

To plot the current graph, due to performance, I moved to `sfdp` (e.g.,
`sfdp foo.dot -Goutputorder="edgesfirst" -Goverlap=false -Tpdf -O`). However, I am not able to achieve a good layout to highlight distinct communities by distantiating them. I tried to tune both `K` at graph level, and `len` and/or `weight` at edge level (by setting high values for intra-communities edges, e.g., 1000; and low values for inter-community edges, e.g., 1). `sfdp` seems to ignore weights. Still, as an extension of `fdp`, it should not.

**Examples on a small graph**

*igraph + fruchterman_reingold layout*
[image: igraph + fruchterman_reingold layout]

*sfdp*

[image: sfdp]

Am I missing something? How can I highlight community differences as done in the above link?

Comment: You might want to try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541376/how-to-draw-communities-with-networkx/43541777): basically: 1) partition your nodes into communities; 2) for each community, determine positions of nodes independently; 3) create a new graph, where each node corresponds to a community and edges correspond to the sum of edges/weights between communities; 4) position communities; 5) combine layouts sensibly.

Comment: You may want to consider Gephi.  You can pause the force calcs once it stabilizes.